# How To Find Minimum Prerequisites for April 2017 KB4015550 Windows 8.1 Update?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-8.1

I'm attempting to manually install critical-only updates to a Win 8.1 box.

I found April 2017 windows8.1-kb4015550-x64_516ecbc130cb85fe3ae74f04c9f2cc791b669012, which i believe is critical updates only. Great.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015547/windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-update-kb4015547

But, it's prerequisite is April 2014 KB2919355, which is over 700 MB.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2919355/windows-rt-8.1,-windows-8.1,-and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-april-2014

I suspect that, at that size, it's not a critical-only update, but instead includes all updates up to that point (even non-critical stuff not required for the 2017 update). Correct?

If so, how can i identify the absolute minimum prerequisites needed for the April 2017 update? -thx

Comment: can your mark your own answer as accepted please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the KB2919355 prerequisite is already installed in Win 8.1 from the Microsoft [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). I found it in "Installed Updates" screen. Great!

Btw, the April 2017 KB4015550 updater said "searching for updates on your computer" for hours, without ever installing. I fixed that with free Tweaking.com "Windows Repair" tool.